# getting the desirable output with gawk/awk

Tags: command-line, awk, aws

I run the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=ip-address,Values=MY_IP" | grep InstanceId
```

and I get:

```
"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",
```

How can I only get the following:

```
i-b0f13081
```

This is what I tried:

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=ip-address,Values=MY_IP" | grep InstanceId | gawk -F: '{ print $2 }' 
 "i-b0f13081",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk`:

Set `"` as field delimiter, and get the 4th field:

```
% awk -F'"' '{print $4}' <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

---

Similarly `cut`:

```
% cut -d'"' -f4 <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

---

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
% grep -Po ':\s*"\K[^"]+' <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

---

Shell parameter expansion:

```
% var='"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
% var="${var%\"*}"
% echo "${var##*\"}"
i-b0f13081
```

---

`sed`:

```
% sed -E 's/^[^:]+:[^"]+"([^"]+).*/\1/' <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

---

`perl`:

```
% perl -pe 's/^[^:]+:[^"]+"([^"]+).*/$1/' <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

---

`python`:

```
% python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().split("\"")[3]' <<<'"InstanceId": "i-b0f13081",'
i-b0f13081
```

Comment: Nice answer....